# How can I separate out multiple values from a column via another table?

Tags: sql

I have a table named `Team`. Each record can have more than one member. Rather than jamming members comma separated value, I am hoping to use separate table to meet the requirement. `Id` is `primary key`.

```
----------------------------
| Id  | Name  | Member
----------------------------
| 1   | TeamA | Jim, Jack
----------------------------
| 2   | TeamB | Micah
```

I thought of creating a table named `User`. `UserId` is the `PK` and `TeamId` is `FK`.

```
--------------------------
| UserId  | Name  | TeamId
--------------------------
| 123     | Jim   |  1 
--------------------------
| 456     | Jack  |  1
--------------------------
| 789     | Micah |  2
```

Then I want parent table `Team` be able to refer `Jim and Jack` from its child table but I am not sure how to represent it in `one to many relationship`... I know below expression is not correct....

```
------------------------
| id  | Name  | Member
------------------------
| 1   | TeamA | 123, 456
```

Comment: You're correct to make a users table that lists the user's team. Not sure you need a column for members for each team. You can query with a join on team and users then group by team id to get the data.

Comment: why do you need to have child table references in parent table? if this 1 to many relationship, then having just TeamId would solve the (most of the) scenarios. So I would like to hear the use case on why you want to have references?

Comment: What database?  this looks like it might be mySQL.

Comment: Maybe like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you need to create a mapping table to represent the Team, Member relationship, which would make this a many-to-many relationship.

```
TeamMemberMap - TeamId, MemberId
```

Comment: ty for your time! I thought about having a mapping table but I couldn't refer from `Team` to `Mapping` table in unique way... I think I realized misunderstanding. I don't need to keep `Members` column.

Comment: or as you and @Pilan said, I could use this mapping table just having `TeamId(FK), MemberId(FK)`. This would work for me also.

Answer (score 1):

(Table) Team:

```
TeamId(PK), Name
```

(Table) Member:

```
MemberId(Pk), Name
```

Case 1 (one to many):
Every Member can be in one team:
Simply add `TeamId`(FK) to Member Table

Case 2 (many to many):
Every Member can be in as many teams as you want:
Add a linking table:

(Table) TeamMember:

```
TeamId(FK), MemberId(FK)
```

Answer (score 0):

That indeed means to normalize data further meaning to split tables your data isnt atomic at each column level. Hence should be normalized to avoid difficulties in data retrievel.

Users Table

```
   User Id(pk) TeamId(fk)
```

Members Table

```
 TeamId(pk) , MemberId, NAME
```

Query

```
   Select 
   u.userid, memberid, m.namefrom 
      users u join members m
   On u.userid=m.memberid and
    u.teamid=m.teamid
```